# Right to left page flow in Indesign CC 2017 (Mac OS)

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

**Hi all,** I have checked other answers but don’t see specifics on this: I have Indesign CC2017 (Mac OS). I am working on a book with both Hebrew and English—trying to do a page flow from right to left. Any answers I have seen in the Adobe site and elsewhere, show screenshots that do *not match* what I am able to pull up. I have tried to follow step by step and change preferences etc but so far no luck. I have no problem with individual paragraphs flowing right to left thru the Single line World Composer, but with the general document—no luck. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: If your screenshots do not match the ones you see in tutorials, are the tutorials perhaps made with the Middle Eastern version of InDesign (which I believe has right-to-left flowing as its default) and yours isn't?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet—Thanks for responding. With CC 2017, the ME version is not as relevant (unless of course you live purchased or lived “over there,” and I HAVE worked in ME versions of Illustrator, so I know there are some major differences. Where I am stymied is trying to set up the capabilities in the preferences with CC 2017 which is what these various sites were showing... Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

**Got it!** It’s true the 2017 CC has in it the capability to format this way, instead of payimg for and adding on capabilities like the old days.

So the Arabic/Hebrew version of same InDesign has to be downloaded. Languages adjusted in Creative Cloud prefs. After that, it’s simply a matter of going to Layout pull down menu / Reverse Layout (and fine-tune any details there). Voila!